# mean of negative bionomial distribution

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

Is the mean of a negative binomial distribution for rate can be calculated as the arithmetic mean of the observed rate? I know it is true for count data, but not sure if it is the same for rate (count/time interval) with lambda=(count/time interval)*time interval. To illustrate my question, assuming an experiment observes the first 3 cases:
-3 events in 1.2 year;
-1 event in 0.8 year;
-6 events in 2 years;
If I would like to know the mean assuming the data follow a negative binomial model, can I simply calculate the arithmetic mean: [(3/1.2)+(1/0.8)+(6/2)]/3 for the Negative Binomial mean?

Comment: This is a very disjointed paragraph whose meaning is difficult to decipher.  Would you perhaps be asking whether the mean of observed rates can be used to *estimate* the rate parameter of a negative binomial distribution?  If so, the answer is *of course* and the better question to ask is "how well does this estimate work?"  For instance, is it unbiased? Is it minimum-variance? What loss functions does it optimize?  *Etc.*  Otherwise, could you explain what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond!  My question is actually simply whether the NB mean and arithmetic means of rates are the same.  A coworker tried to explain to us that the rate ratio of NB is the ratio of mean rate of group 1 divided by the mean rate of group 2 using the arithmetic mean (b/c its the same as NB mean).  I was also confused how this relate to the equation that mean of NB=(1-p/p)*r

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "groups," because you don't mention them or describe them in your post and that concept is unrelated to the mean of the NB distribution.  Please be aware of the distinction (a big one) between the arithmetic mean of *data* and the arithmetic mean of a *distribution* (such as the NB) assumed to generate those data.

Comment: Sorry, it is confusing to bring up 'group' which is not relevant.  What I was trying to be certain is whether we can use the arithmetic mean of the observed rates as the mean of rates if the underlying distribution that generates these rates is NB.  It seems that the answer is yes.  I am learning how to estimate dispersion next and hope to be able to write a random number generating function in SAS for NB to generate rates.